# Create dynamic column and row with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs and i want to create dynamic row with ng-repeat but unable to achieve. I will clear after see my code. Here is my code and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/31810/):-

### td.controllers.js

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.products = [{
            name: 'Abc'
        }, {
            name: 'Bil'
        }, {
            name: 'Smart'
        }];
}
```

### td.html

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan="2">Month</th>
                                <th ng-repeat="product in products" colspan="2">{{product.name}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>A</th> //I want to dynamic it
                                <th>B</th> //
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
   </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

My desire output is:-

```
-----------------------------
Month | Abc | Bil | Smart
      | A|B | A|B | A|B
----------------------------
```

Comment: Where do you want A|B? in header or body?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th rowspan="2">Month</th>
                                <th ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.name}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th> <!--I want to dynamic it-->
                                <th ng-repeat="product in products">A|B</th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
   </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Try this code
Here table header is created dynically and table data also.

Let me know if you are getting nay problem

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
<html>
<head>
<script Src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

<script>
 var app=angular.module("myapp", []);
 app.controller("namesctrl", function($scope){

  $scope.products = [{
        name: 'Abc'
    }, {
        name: 'Bil'
    }, {
        name: 'Smart'
    }];

 });

 
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="namesctrl">
  <div>
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Month</th>
        <th ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th ng-repeat="product in products">A|B</th> 
    </tr>
    </thead>
   </table>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```